# How to debounce the redux dispatch, but not the useState componenet update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, debouncing

I have a simple slider component from Material-UI v4, mostly taken from [this example](https://v4.mui.com/components/slider/#slider-with-input-field).

I want to update the UI, both the slider and the number (which is displayed in the UI) 'instantly', but debounce the dispatch to redux, so it doesn't update the store unnecessarily.

This is what I've done so far to modify the example:

```js
import { debounce } from 'lodash';
import { useDispatch } from 'redux';
import { updatingAction } from 'action/foo';
export default function InputSlider() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isReduxInSyncRef = useRef(false);
  const reduxValue = useSelector(getReduxValue);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(30);

  const debouncedDispatch = debounce((value) => {
    dispatch(updatingAction(value));
    isReduxInSyncRef.current = true;
  }, 200);

  const updateStateAndRedux = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    isReduxInSyncRef.current = false;
  }

  const handleSliderChange = (event, newValue) => {
    updateStateAndRedux(newValue);
  };

  const handleInputChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    updateStateAndRedux(value === '' ? '' : Number(value));
    debouncedDispatch(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (reduxValue !== value && isReduxInSyncRef.current) {
      setValue(reduxValue);
    }
  }, [value, reduxValue]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography id="input-slider" gutterBottom>
        Volume
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
        <Grid item>
          <VolumeUp />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Slider
            value={typeof value === 'number' ? value : 0}
            onChange={handleSliderChange}
            onChangeCommitted={(event, value) => debouncedDispatch(value)}
            aria-labelledby="input-slider"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Input
            className={classes.input}
            value={value}
            margin="dense"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            inputProps={{
              step: 10,
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              type: 'number',
              'aria-labelledby': 'input-slider',
            }}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Because the slider and value need to move together, when I debounced the whole thing (redux + `useState`), I couldn't move the slider at all.

Using `onChangeCommitted` for the dispatch only helps the slider, but it seems like the number input onChange (`handleInputChange`) is firing the dispatch for every value, without being debounced.

What have I done wrong, and is there an easier/better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you need to use `onChangeCommitted` at all. The `onChange` handler should be sufficient. Here's what I would change: Initialize the `value` as local state in the component only once when the component mounts, based on the value from `useSelector`. When a change occurs, do two things: 1) update the local state value, 2) call the debounced function that dispatches the new value. Every change of the slider will eventually propagate the change to the redux store, with the latest value taking precedence. There is no reason to deal with keeping them in sync as far as I can see.

Comment: @timotgl I'm not at work to try that, but unless I'm mistaken I did try a version of that before and it didn't work. Will check for certain tomorrow however